# Are std::find and std::map.find both O(logN)?

Tags: c++, stl

Are `std::find` and `std::map.find` both O(logN)?
If they are, how does `std::find` implement search over `std::map` in logarithmic time?

Is the implementation of `std::find` specialized for the `std::map` use case?

Comment: Vaguely related: the closest non-`map`-specific thing to `std::map::find` is arguably [`std::binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search), which seeks the value in a pre-sorted random-access container (e.g. `vector`, array, `deque`).

Comment: @TonyD I think you mean `std::lower_bound`. `binary_search` doesn't return an iterator.

Comment: @MarkRansom: well, when calling `mymap.find(x)` for a `!= mymap.end()` membership test (which is a more trivial but very common use, though arguably best replaced with `mymap.count()`), `binary_search` is more similar, while when you're interested in the position of a match `lower_bound`'s needed (with a check that you're not at a greater-than-wanted key).

Answer (score 13):

No, `std::find` is O(N), regardless of the container. It doesn't know the "container", there is no specialization for `std::map`. `std::find` uses only the iterators, which do not have information about the underlying container. According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), the implementation is equivalent to:

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
InputIt find(InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (*first == value) {
            return first;
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

According to the C++ standard (emphasize mine):

**25.2.5 Find [alg.find]**

```
template<class InputIterator, class T>
  InputIterator find(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                     const T& value);
...
```

1. Returns: The first iterator `i` in the range `[first,last)` for which the following corresponding conditions hold: `*i == value`, . . . . Returns `last` if no such iterator is found.
2. **Complexity: At most last - first applications of the corresponding predicate.**